# MYSQL Database Joined tables query pulling up limited records and adding results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database that I"m trying to use one Query to get data from both for a specific report.

Table one is "Movies" and it has these fields:

- Movies_ID
- Name
- Season

Table two is "Boxoffice" sales income for each movie:

- Boxoffice_ID
- Movies_ID
- Date
- Amount

I want to run a query to compare the opening weekends for each movie in a given season and return them as one dataset with the amounts collected added together. So I want to take each movie and get the first three days of box office for each film and add them up so that I get back a query like this

1. Movie A, 49.1 Million
2. Movie B, 42.2 Million
3. Movie C, 29.5 Million

Please note the amount collected only needs to output the number and I'll take care of the formatting. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to only query the first three days of box office for each movie and adding them together.

I know I could run one query and get the movies with box office and then loop over that and re-query the database but I know that with a lot of movies that isn't the most efficient way of doing things. I'm not sure if there is a way to do all of this (first three days of each movie added together) in one query but I wanted to see if someone with more advanced knowledge could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.Name, SUM(COALESCE(b.Amount,0)) totalAmount
FROM    Movies a
        LEFT JOIN BoxOffice b
            ON a.Movies_ID = b.Movies_ID
WHERE   b.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -3 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY a.Name
```

if the value of `CURDATE()` is 2012-11-06 (*which is today*), it will calculate from *2012-11-03* until *2012-11-06*.

*followup question, how do you calculate the date? by day? by week? or what?*

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.Name, SUM(COALESCE(b.Amount,0)) totalAmount
FROM    Movies a
        LEFT JOIN BoxOffice b
            ON a.Movies_ID = b.Movies_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  movies_ID, MIN(date) minDate
            FROM    BoxOffice
            GROUP BY Movies_ID
        ) c ON a.Movies_ID = c.Movies_ID
WHERE   DATE(b.date) BETWEEN DATE(c.minDate) AND 
                             DATE(DATE_ADD(c.minDate,INTERVAL 3 DAY))
GROUP BY a.Name
```

Comment: Each entry in box office is the total for that movie for one day. So it would be 1. 10/25/12, Movie A, 5,272,293 2. 10/25/12 Movie B, 3,295,682.    The problem I didn't specify in the detail (sorry) is that more movies are coming out each week. Each season spans multiple months and I only want the first three days for each film. I thought maybe it could just pull the three days for each film with the lowest date values.

Comment: maybe my updated answer could help? you also want to calculate the first three days where the movie was released? and in this case you stored it in `DATE`?

Comment: see my updated answer. it will calculate the first three days since the movie was released.

Comment: Okay got it to work now with the actual table names and the only thing is it was pulling 4 days worth of box office total. I changed it to Interval 2 day and it's working perfectly. This is by far the most complicated SQL I've ever had to perform and you are brilliant for your suggestion I probably would have taken days to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

just join the tables on Movies_ID and add WHERE with TIMEDIFF between issue date and Date being 3 days.